# Traversal/lens with a monad side effect

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens, lenses

I have a traversal `mytraversal` and a function `f: a -> a` that I can use as follows: `mydata & mytraversal %~ f`.

However, what do I  use if I instead have `f: a -> m a` for a monad `m`? In my case, it's a state monad, and I want to modify items of a structure, modifying the current state.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
type Traversal s t a b = forall f. Applicative f => (a -> f b) -> s -> f t
```

So, really, just

```
mydata & mytraversal f
```

should do. If you want an operator, it's called [`(%%~)`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.17.1/docs/Control-Lens-Operators.html#v:-37--37--126-).

```
mydata & mytraversal %%~ f
```